# Check if integer has even number of digits

Tags: equation-solving

I want to check if a number has an even or odd number of digits.

`10` would be even because it has 2 digits

`300` would be odd because it has 3 digits

`986786` would be even, because it has 6 digits

Seems like I would be dividing it by a power of 10, is that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`IntegerLength`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerLength.html):

```
OddQ@IntegerLength[{10, 300, 986786}]
(* {False, True, False} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
EvenQ@Floor@Log[10, N@{10, 300, 986786}]
(* {False, True, False} *)
```

Comment: good approach to know in case you need to port your code.  The N@ isn't needed by the way (maybe it affects performance though )

Comment: Indeed, it is two orders of magnitude faster to give Log the float value than to let Floor process the integer result. `IntegerLength` is another order of magnitude faster than that..